# How to create chart with xlsxwriter with no "Horizontal (Value) Axis"

Tags: excel, charts, axis, xlsxwriter

How to remove "Horizontal (Value) Axis" from excel 2013 chart with xlsxwriter.

Xlsxwriter documentation is silent about it.

I have tried:

`chart.set_x_axis({None: True})
chart.set_y_axis({None: True})`
But it does not work.

On excel I am able to remove axis by selecting itand hitting *delete* key.

The thing i want to remove is selected in redbox.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the axis [`label_position` (docs)](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart.html#chart-set-x-axis) to `none` to hide the axis:

```
chart.set_x_axis({'label_position': 'none'})
```

For example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_column('A1', [10, 40, 50])

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'bar', 'subtype': 'percent_stacked'})

chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1', 'data_labels': {'value': 1}})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$2', 'data_labels': {'value': 1}})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$3', 'data_labels': {'value': 1}})

chart.set_legend({'none': True})
chart.set_x_axis({'label_position': 'none'})

worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your example works. For some reason it does not work in my code.
However, I found that it is possible to do
chart.set_x_axis({'visible': 0}) to have same effect.